# String spliting

Tags: r, string, split

Is there function in R that could make following:

I have column, where each row has string, where words (countries) are seperated with commas. But I would like to make new column, that has those same countries, but gives me following

i make example with one of the rows

```r
old column value "Eesti, Soome, Soome, Soome, Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Eesti, Eesti, Soome"
new column value "Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Soome" 

col1 <- 1:2
col2 <- c("Eesti, Soome, Soome, Soome, Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Eesti, Eesti, Soome", "Ukraina, Eesti, Luksembourg, Luksembourg, Eesti, Eesti, Eesti")

dt <- data.frame(PERSON_ID = col1,
COUNTRIES = col2)

dt
# PERSON_ID, COUNTRIES
# 1 Eesti, Soome, Soome, Soome, Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Eesti, Eesti, Soome
# 2 Ukraina, Eesti, Luksembourg, Luksembourg, Eesti, Eesti, Eesti
```

but i would like to add new column, where i could have something, that are in COUNTRIES2, so i mean col3 variable

```r
col3 <- c("Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Soome", "Ukraina, Eesti, Luksembourg, Eesti")

# PERSON_ID, COUNTRIES, COUNTRIES2
# 1 Eesti, Soome, Soome, Soome, Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Eesti, Eesti, Soome   Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Soome
# 2 Ukraina, Eesti, Luksembourg, Luksembourg, Eesti, Eesti, Eesti    Ukraina, Eesti, Luksembourg, Eesti
```

I have tried multible things.

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of `dput(<your data frame>)` into your post or `dput(head(<your data frame>))` if you have a large data frame. Also include code you have tried, any relevant errors, and expected output. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. [Do not post images of code and/or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6382434).

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please edit it to provide R code that creates your sample input, and also shows you sample output in a clearer way. I can't tell if your values are one string that need to be edited, or multiple rows of a data frame that need to be filtered, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could do something like this...

```
df <- data.frame(string = "Eesti, Soome, Soome, Soome, Eesti, 
                           Soome, Eesti, Eesti, Eesti, Soome")

df$y <- sapply(df$string, \(x) paste(rle(unlist(strsplit(x, ", ")))$values,
                                     collapse = ", "))

df$y
[1] "Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Soome"
```

This splits the string at `,`  and applies the `rle` function, which does run-length-encoding. The output of `rle` is a list that includes `$value` specifying the values of each run. The values are then pasted back together as a single string. The `sapply` applies this function to each element of the dataframe column.

Comment: code golf, `paste(..., collapse = ", ")` --> `toString(...)`

Answer (score 0):

We could first split strings in the input column with `strsplit()`, this will generate a list of splits; applying `rle()` on every item in the list through `lapply()` generates a list of *run-length-encoding* objects, from those we only keep `values` vectors; as a final step we'll collapse all those vectors in a list back together, now through `sapply()` to get a vector instead of a list.

```r
col1 <- 1:2
col2 <- c("Eesti, Soome, Soome, Soome, Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Eesti, Eesti, Soome", 
          "Ukraina, Eesti, Luksembourg, Luksembourg, Eesti, Eesti, Eesti")
dt <- data.frame(PERSON_ID = col1,
                 COUNTRIES = col2)
dt
#>   PERSON_ID
#> 1         1
#> 2         2
#>                                                              COUNTRIES
#> 1 Eesti, Soome, Soome, Soome, Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Eesti, Eesti, Soome
#> 2        Ukraina, Eesti, Luksembourg, Luksembourg, Eesti, Eesti, Eesti

dt$COUNTRIES2 <- strsplit(dt$COUNTRIES, ", ", fixed = TRUE) |>
  lapply(\(x) rle(x)$values) |>
  sapply(paste, collapse = ", ")

subset(dt, select = -COUNTRIES)
#>   PERSON_ID                               COUNTRIES2
#> 1         1 Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Soome, Eesti, Soome
#> 2         2       Ukraina, Eesti, Luksembourg, Eesti
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>